# Primefaces running in Tomcat and Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, jsf, primefaces, tomcat7, java

I developed a web app with jsf and Primefaces in my PC. If I run it on localhost, it's displayed ok

Now I want to deploy it on a server, so I have installed same jdk version and copied my tomcat directory on a virtual machine.

Application runs right, but it's not displayed right in the same IE navigator! Buttons are hide, heades with wrong size....

The only difference is that my PC has Windows 7 32 bit and the VM it 's an Windows Server 2008 64bits

Any suggestion would be very appreciated

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The part *"and copied my tomcat directory on a virtual machine"* is very suspicious. This is not the normal way of deploying Java web applications. Can you please describe what steps exactly you performed?

Comment: I have a Tomcat 7.0.8 already configured to use with jsf. I run it on my Pc and the application works right. Even I tried same procedure on a VM with Windows XP and works right aswell. Only in that server doesn't works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have right `css` in place, I had similar kind of issues where components where displayed properly on chrome but not on IE and for me issue was related to `rime.css`, make sure you have proper css in page, that probably is the reason for your challenge.

Comment: I think it isn't a CSS problem, because I open one IE window with my local application and other with the server application and I don't see the same displayed